# Is there a word for "dissecting a sentence and naming its parts"? (example below)

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Such as:

> The great people of that great nation had been producing the greatest per capita carbon footprint for decades when they realized that the science was right and their practices were unsustainable.

I've gone thus far and have some questions.

> 1-SUBJECT A..The B..great C..people D..of E..that F..great G..nation
>
> 2-VERB A..had B..been C..producing
>
> 3-PREDICATE A..the B..greatest C..per D..capita E..carbon F..footprint
>
> 4-PREDICATE (Q1-still predicate?) A..since B..their C..industrialization
>
> 5-CONJUNCTION A..when
>
> 6-SUBJECT A..they
>
> 7-VERB A..realized
>
> 8-CONJUNCTION A..that
>
> 9-SUBJECT A..the B..science
>
> 10-VERB A..was
>
> 11-PREDICATE A..right
>
> 12-CONJUNCTION A..and
>
> 13-SUBJECT A..their B..practices
>
> 14-VERB A..were
>
> 15-PREDICATE A..unsustainable.

Q2-Is this a run on sentence?

Q3-If this is a valid sentence, could someone help me go further by labeling each word of each part of the sentence?

Q4-Could it be made better?

Much obliged.

Comment: Generally it's called "parsing and construing" a sentence. Though the example you give above is incorrect in many ways.

Comment: @Lawler - please develop your comment.

Comment: We don't do homework here, but I'll start by pointing out that #3 above is a noun phrase and the direct object of the verb, and that #4 is an adverbial phrase. Also that this style of list is of no help to anyone in understanding the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's often called *parsing* or *diagramming* the sentence.

As a start, it looks to me like the top-level construct is "... had been ... when ..." or, with labels, "(...)[subject] (had been)[primary verb] (...)[continuing past-tense clause] when[conjunction] (...)[past-test clause]". This frame holds a noun phrase (the subject) and two verb phrases.

Q2. It's not a run-on sentence. All the parts are supported and connected.

Q3. The sentence appears valid. Perhaps a bit long-winded.

Q4. The repetition of the word *great* may be more appropriate in some contexts and less so in others. For a speech or a poem, it could be very effective. For an academic essay, you should probably tried to use more varied terms, but without sounding like you over-used the thesaurus.

Comment: What do you mean by "over used the Thesaurus"? Does it sound pompous? What I need here is to have a sentence using sentence structure as much as possible without sounding so.

Comment: I mean that, if you look up synonyms of the word 'great' in the thesaurus, it can make the sentence sound really odd if you use too many unfamiliar words.

Answer (score 1):

You already have answers on most of your question. As to making the sentence better:

The word `when` does not fit the sentence. It sounds like they realized the science was right while still generating that high carbon footprint. If I am reading it right, the word should be `until.` Also, `they realized that the science was right` is too weak of a statement. It should be written in stronger terms, or drop the word *that.*

I wonder if by "great people" they mean the elite, or the captains of industry, or businessmen. It could be written without the word *great* as in *the people*, so perhaps they intended a specific group of *great people*. I would make one other change. Instead of the past perfect verb phrase. `had been producing` use the simple past tense verb `produced.`

Comment: Hey Cindy, I need to keep it in the Past Perfect Continuous in order to show the verb phrase. "Until" does sound much better and dropping that "that" gives me an opportunity to point out the omissibility of the conjunction. Big help. It's a shame I can't choose two answers. As for the "great" part it has been done in order to hint on the fact that unfortunately the human conception of "great nation" is so tightly bound to consumerism. It is now the U.S. but soon to be China (I wonder If they call the Great Wall great over there).

Comment: Stronger terms?